# change values of status column to "old" with time trigger, google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am working on google script to create a simple issue tracker.

On form submission it creates the issue as "`new`" under "`column`". I am trying to change the values of '`Status`' column to '`old`' at midnight. I am stuck with code.

for time I was thinking of setting up time driven trigger at midnight. Kindly help.

```
function changeStatus() {

    // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var row = sheet.getLastRow();
    //var lastRow = sheet.getR
    // Set the status of the new ticket to 'New'.
    // Column F is the Status column


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    //var range = sheet.getRange("F2:F4");
    //var row = range.getRow();

    for (var i = 0; i >= row; i--) {
        sheet.getRange(i, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("old");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what the problem is or what you want help with.

If the function isn't triggering then it's probably because `getActiveSpreadsheet` doesn't work well with time triggers, since when it triggers your spreadsheet likely won't be open (active). Use `openByID` instead (the ID can be found in the URL).

As far as the rest of the code, seems fine if you only have two statuses and efficiency isn't too important. If you have more than two statuses, you'll have to check if the status is `new` and then change it `old`, leaving other statuses as is.

Also, you can consider storing a persistent value to dictate where you left off. Logically speaking, nothing should revert back to `new`, so you should not need to change the status of previous rows. With that in mind, if you start from where you left off the day before, it will save you from having to loop through all rows.